# Max allocation of Ram

Tags: centos, 64-bit

I am using  4 cloud servers with Centos 6 and 7  from a third-party and they are extended ram size up to 160 GB, But  I need to extended 250 GB ,But they told in kvm couldn't extend more than 160.  Is  KVM architecture support maximum of 160 GB ram memory for each server? else is it support more than 160 GB?

Answer (score 2):

[No, it's not](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-kvm-limits) from the software side. The limit is 4000 GB in EL6/7. However, that doesn't mean that your provider can't set up a lower limit if they wish to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of KVM they are running and who distributed it.

No version of KVM distributed by Red Hat had those particular [guest memory limits](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-kvm-limits), so they're definitely running something oddball (like perhaps Proxmox?).

Current versions of KVM will support guests with up to 240 vCPUs and 4000 GB of RAM, which should be enough for most workloads, for now...